# Amazon DynamoDb Database

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to create more than one databases in one aws dynamodb account ? e.g one database for university who manages university tables and one database for school who manages school tables.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct but the more complete answer is that DynamoDB operates with tables and items. There is no concept of a *"database"* per se, as that would imply relating multiple tables, which would go against the non-relational aspect of DynamoDB.

So, long story short, yes, you can create multiple tables, that each is part of a different application, all in the same AWS account, and/or region. But the logical relationship (such as belonging to the same application, or storing related data) must all be modelled at the application level. DynamoDB doesn't care. It doesn't even care much about the schema of items in the same table, much less about different tables.

Comment: So, long story short: no. You can only have **one** DynamoDB for each region, but you can create multiple tables. As this looks like someone who is known with SQL but not with NoSQL, your answer might bring some confusion. The first part is very useful.

Comment: @JeroenE no - DynamoDB has tables, but no databases. And a region is definitely not a database either. Please don't confuse the two. You could think of a DynamoDB table as a database if you will but that is about it. I think they should have called them dictionaries not tables. That would have saved a lot of confusion.

Comment: that's what I said? I've not used "database" once in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you're not able to create more then one DynamoDB for each account on the same **region**. So the answer is no. 
Our solution to this was to **prefix each table** to each application. For example:

```
appl1_tableName
appl1_tableName
appl2_tableName
```

Hopefully this helps you out.